# (Scheme) How can I apply the function to every sublist in a list?

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to remove the first element in every sublist in the list. I need the cdar of every sublist. I tried using map but it didn't work. I get voids for some reason. Should I use recursion instead?

My code:

```
(define (rd data)
 (map (lambda (x)
        (if (null? x)
            (cdar x))) 
      data))
```

I want this:

```
'((1 (r (3 4))) (4 (d (5 6)))) -> ((r (3 4)) (d (5 6)))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The values you want are the `cadr` of each element of the list.

Comment: You're only calling `cdar` when the element is null. I think you have your test backwards, you want to extract the `cadr` when it's _not_ null.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot to put the statement if it was null. I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors, pointed out earlier plus a need to handle the `if` alternate, resolve to:

```
(define (rd data)
 (map (lambda (x)
        (if (not (null? x)
            (cadr x)
            x))
      data))
```

Answer (score 1):

About your code: the procedure that is passed to `map` doesn't have to test if the element is `null`, `map` takes care of that part. The procedure only has to deal with *what* is going to be done to each of the elements, `map` will apply it to each element of the list in turn (in this case, the elements happen to be sublists) and return a list with the results.

Understanding the above, notice that the procedure just needs to extract the second element of each sublist. A simpler solution would be to write:

```
(define (rd data)
  (map (lambda (x) (cadr x)) data))
```

... But that's too verbose, we're applying `cadr` to each element in turn and nothing else, and that's equivalent to this:

```
(define (rd data)
  (map cadr data))
```

... Or even clearer (works in Racket):

```
(define (rd data)
  (map second data))
```

Any way the result is as expected:

```
(rd '((1 (r (3 4))) (4 (d (5 6)))))
=> '((r (3 4)) (d (5 6)))
```